# How to search a directory for files that begin with something then get the one that was modified most recently

Tags: c#, search, directory, fileinfo

What I want to do is search/scan a directory for multiple files beginning with something, then get the file that was last modified most recently. For example, I want to search the directory Prefetch for files that begin with "apple", "pear", and "orange". These files may not exist, but if they do, and say there are files that begin with apple and files that begin with pear, out of all of those files, I want to get the one that was modified most recently. The code below allows me do to this but search only 1 thing.

```
DirectoryInfo prefetch = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Windows\\Prefetch");
FileInfo[] apple = prefetch.GetFiles("apple*");
if (apple.Length == 0)
   // Do something
else
{
   double lastused = DateTime.Now.Subtract(
                     apple.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
                          .FirstOrDefault().LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes;
   int final = Convert.ToInt32(lastused);
}
```

Basically, how can I make that code search 'apple', 'pear' etc. instead of just apple? I don't know if you can modify the code above to do that or if you have to change it completely. I've been trying to figure this out for hours and can't do it.

Comment: Just call GetFiles three times with the appropriate pattern, store the result in three different arrays then add them to a single list. Now you can apply the order by descending and get the first element of the list. Not clear what you are trying to do with that calculantion at the end

Comment: I can see how this would work and would probably solve my issue, but how would I store them and add them to a list?

Comment: Declare a **List<FileInfo>** then use the AddRange to add the three set of files to the same list. Now, OrderByDescending and FirstOrDefault on that list will give you the most recently written file of the set.

Comment: I got this to work, thank you so much. Can't mark it as correct since it's not an answer but thanks ;p

Comment: Well, added an answer to simplify further the loop over the patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comments you can't use *DirectoryInfo.GetFiles* to return list of *FileInfo* with so different patterns. Just one pattern is supported.

As others as already shown, you can prepare a list of patterns and then call in a loop the GetFiles on each pattern.

However, I would show you the same approach, but done with just one line of code in Linq.

```
List<string> patterns = new List<string> { "apple*", "pear*", "orange*" };
DirectoryInfo prefetch = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Windows\Prefetch");  

var result = patterns.SelectMany(x => prefetch.GetFiles(x))
                     .OrderByDescending(k => k.LastWriteTime)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, *result* is a FileInfo with the most recent update. Of course, if no files matches the three patterns, then *result* will be null. A check before using that variable is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of files that match the prefixes then check the date of those files, something like (not tested):

```
List<string> files=new List<string>();
foreach(var str in prefixes)
  files.AddRange(dirInfo.GetFiles(str));

return (from d in (from name in files select File.GetLastAccessTime(name)) orderby d descending).FirstOrDefault();
```

prefixes is the list of search patterns, and dirInfo is a DirectoryInfo object.

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles returns FileInfos, then you don't need that last line but just OrderByDescending and FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list

```
   List<string> patterns = new List<string> { "apple*", "pear*", "orange*" };
   DirectoryInfo prefetch = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Windows\\Prefetch");         

   foreach (var pattern in patterns) {
       FileInfo[] files = prefetch.GetFiles(pattern);
       var lastAccessed = files.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastAccessTime).FirstOrDefault();
       if (lastAccessed != null) {
           var minutes = DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastAccessed.LastAccessTime).TotalMinutes;
       }
   }
```